# Virtualbox and networking

Tags: networking, windows, virtualbox

I have installed Win 7 in Virtual Box but am unable to see my NAS Drive. I have checked under network and can see the internet. I looked under network in Virtual Box and it is set to NAT.

Answer (score 2):

Switch to "*bridged networking*" - than you'll get an IP of your LAN subnet in your virtual machine and therefore can connect to your NAS.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can't see your NAS, its broadcast can't reach your virtual machine when using NAT. Think as your virtual machine is behind a router.

- The best is what [Mr.Gosh recommends (*bridged networking*)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627946/virtualbox-and-networking/627958#627958).
- Another option is to enter your NAS IP directly from the virtual machine (If you know its IP or it's static)